# Using two gesture recognizners toghether in flutter

Tags: flutter, uigesturerecognizer

I am using one gesture detector(which is big) over another gesture detector,

```
 Widget _sliderWidget() {
    return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        child: widget.child,
        onHorizontalDragStart: onHorizontalDragStart,
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalDragUpdate,
        onHorizontalDragEnd: onHorizontalDragEnd,
        onTapDown: _onTapDown)
}
```

and sencond view is

```
 Widget _paintWidget() {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onHorizontalDragDown: _onHorizontalDragDown,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: _renderCanvas(),
    );
  }
```

taps not recognize in `_paintWidget()` view , how can I  fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping both childs of the GestureDetectors inside a Stack and wrapping the Stack inside a GestureDetector? And then check with coordinated which method to call? But are both Widgets on the same page? Are both inside a Stack? Maybe try to change the order inside the Stack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792718/multiply-gesture-detector-in-flutter

Comment: More deitals you can find here