# Multiply gesture detector in flutter

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have two views one over another and  want get touches in both views. But now get touches only second view.
How can I configure `GestureDetector` that all touches will be send ***both widgets***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TestPage();

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: Stack(
        children: [_renderFirstWidget(), _renderSecondWidget()],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _renderFirstWidget() {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('first');
          },
          child: Container(height: 150, width: 150, color: Colors.greenAccent)),
    );
  }

  Widget _renderSecondWidget() {
    return Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('second');
          },
            child: Container(
                height: 350,
                width: 350,
                color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.3))));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have a single onTap event for both views, wrap the stack in a GestureDetector, instead of wrapping each views in GestureDetector.

Comment: in future I will add ``onDragUpdate``, and more functions. If I Wrap the Stack, my secondView not over firstView